# Guzzle returning a 404 on a valid URL

Tags: guzzle

I'm using Guzzle with CurlAuthPlugin to authenticate. When I run the code, I get

```
Client error response\ [status code] 404\ [reason phrase] Not Found\ [url] https:\/\/api.buto.tv\/v2\/video\/tag\/v2\/video\/tag\/
```

The code I'm using is:

```
$client = new Client(<URL>);

    // Add the auth plugin to the client object
    $authPlugin = new CurlAuthPlugin(<APIKEY>, 'x');
    $client->addSubscriber($authPlugin);

    $response = $client->get('v2/video/tag/')->send();
```

But the URL is perfectly valid a I can paste that in to a browser and it works fine

I've also tried:

```
 $client = new Client('https://api.buto.tv');
    $request = $client->get('v2/video/tag/');
    $request->setAuth('user', 'pass');
    $response = $request->send();
```

But I get the same error. I have output the URL it's requesting with `echo $request->getUrl();` and if I copy and paste the URL in to a browser, the URL is fine

Comment: even i am having the same problem. i am using http://click.in/ working well on browser. but not on guzzle. could that be a problem with disabled cookie. or some security features implemented on the website.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be missing a slash '/' after api.buto.tv, so the url is resolving to 'https://api.buto.tvv2/video/tag/' instead of 'https://api.buto.tv/v2/video/tag/'.

```
$client = new Client('https://api.buto.tv/');
$request = $client->get('v2/video/tag/');
```